# Android - GridView - how to align items to left, center, right in one row?

Tags: android, gridview, alignment, gravity

i am making an app with GridView which has 3 columns.

[image]

As you see, the top three buttons are in the relative layout. Each item is aligned to the left, center and right respectively.

The bottom items in the gray background are in the gridView.
(The bg color of gridview is gray.
The issue is that I want to align these three items in the grid view just like the one in the relative layout.
So the FB button should stick to the left, Twitter button in the center, SMS button to the right.
However, I don't know how to set their gravity separatley.
The gridView below is applied with orientation:center.
Is there a way to set the gravity of these separately? 
Any suggesetion is appreciated.

Comment: are you using baseAdapter?

Comment: Would it be an option to change the relativelayout to match the gridview? It's just that gridviews are a bit funny about how they stretch - you are not guaranteed 3 items per row...BUT, you can get the horizontal spacing between them